# How to setValidators to FormGroup after its initialization

Tags: angular, validation, angular5

I have this FormGroup

```
defaultIdNumberValidator = [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6),
    Validators.maxLength(11)];

this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
  permissions: this.formBuilder.group({
    country: ['', [Validators.required]],
    identityNumber: [null, this.defaultIdNumberValidator],
  }, {validator: [this.validateId]}) 
});
```

and I want to clear and add validators to `identityNumber` depending on some conditions in `this.validateId` method.

```
validateId(input: AbstractControl) {
  if(condition) {
    input.get("identityNumber").clearValidators(); //this is working
  }
  if(condition) {
    input.get("identityNumber").setValidators(this.defaultIdNumberValidator); //not working
  }
}
```

When `setValidators` method is called I get this error (line :109 is line where `setValidators` is called)

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultIdNumberValidator' of undefined
    at RegisterComponent.validateId (register.component.ts:109)
    at eval (forms.js:742)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:742)
    at eval (forms.js:694)
    at eval (forms.js:742)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _executeValidators (forms.js:742)
    at eval (forms.js:694)
    at eval (forms.js:742)
```

---

UPDATE:

I restart development server and now i get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValidators' of undefined
at RegisterComponent.validateId (register.component.ts:109)
at eval (forms.js:742)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at _executeValidators (forms.js:742)
at eval (forms.js:694)
at eval (forms.js:742)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at _executeValidators (forms.js:742)
at eval (forms.js:694)
```

---

UPDATE 2:

I create simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BAWPVsYG323Q461jdUCo?p=preview) to reproduce error. If you first click input and than click somewhere else you get error under it. So this error should be removed when length of input value is >= 2, and should be visible again when is >= 5. I also don't know why error disappear when length of input value is 3 and not 2...

Comment: Can you create a plunkr? Does your validateId method sit in a separate ts file?

Comment: You are obviously losing the reference to 'this' somewhere

Comment: See update. I will try create a plunkr

Comment: I create plunker. See update 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to `bind(this)` to keep the context of `this`. Also you need to use `updateValueAndValidity` for the change of the validators to be updated. There we also need to not emit an event, if you were, this would case looping until your browser crashes. So change the following:

```ts
}, {validator: this.validateId.bind(this)})
```

and the validator would look like this:

```ts
validateId(input: AbstractControl) {
  // ...
  if(...) {
    input.get("identityNumber").clearValidators();
    input.get("identityNumber").updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false, onlySelf:true});
  }
  if(...) {
    input.get("identityNumber").setValidators(this.defaultIdNumberValidator);
    input.get("identityNumber").updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false, onlySelf:true});
  }
}
```

Your **[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/PYz6G49bPWhlUmOPS4O1?p=preview)**